# Alpha/Beta Testing multiplayer feature

Tags: android, testing, google-play-games

I recently integrated google-play-games SDK into my game. I decided to use the real-time multi-player APIs. Now I have this problem: how to test it with my testers community (around 20 people) ?

The game is in alpha testing at the moment (not published). I would prefer an early testing before publishing it. Now I have already created some testing account that I can use for my internal testing, but how to allow my small community to test it?

I mean having just 10-20 people and pretend that they are connected at the same time it seems unachievable considering that my game allow up to 6 people to join a game (using also auto-match feature). I already have a version of my game that is capable to use a simulator (implemented in the code) to play a game (without any human interation) but how to use that in the context of testing? Is there any cloud based service that allow to push the APKs simulators? What's the Google solution for this problem?